# Balzano Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can't seem to wrap my head around what the theorem even means. I can't understand how every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence. That is the theorem by the way.

So is their theorem saying that the sequence {1,2,3} has a convergent sub-sequence? How on earth is that true? Maybe im confused of what's actually considered a sub sequence. Is the sequence {1.5,2.5} a sub sequence of {1,2,3}? Are the numbers inbetween considered to be contained in the sequence?

In reply to comments:
So if a real sequence is [1,4] and a subsequence of that is [2,3] there will be an infinite number of terms but how does it converge if the greatest term in the sub sequence is 3, is it just because there are an infinite number of terms in between?

Comment: A sequence in the sense used in the theorem always has an infinite number of terms.

Comment: So the theorem is just restating the completeness of real numbers for a bounded sequence contained in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The completeness, and that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a Cauchy-subsequence.

Comment: [1,4] is not a sequence. What do you intend to ask in this case?

Comment: Subsequence is just obtained from a sequence by considering subset of elements of the sequence. So $\{1.5,2.5\}$ is not a subsequence of $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: So how does {1,2,3} have a convergent sub sequence of the only sub sequences of it are {1,2} {1,3} {2,3}? I cant see how any of these subsequences are convergent

Comment: {1, 2, 3} is a set, not a sequence.

Comment: I used $\{1,2,3\}$ just for the sake of explaining. Actually the sequence is set having bijection with the set of natural numbers. So the set of the sequence might be like $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,.......,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,....,3,3,3,3,3,3,..........\}$ where 3s follow infinitely further. Note that this IS what a sequence looks like not $\{1,2,3\}$. And clearly we can find $\{1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,........\}$ to be it's convergent subsequence!

Comment: So then wouldnt a bounded sequence just be a set?

Comment: A sequence is a function, it is not a  set.

Comment: Set and Sequence are completely different concepts. ... E.g. $a_{n} = 1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence. $\{1 \}$ is a set. A set can not have repeating elements.

Comment: No! bounded means $|x_n| \lt M \forall n$

Comment: Note that the set I've wrote above is set of the terms of the sequence!

Comment: Clearly the sequence $1,1,1,1,........,2,2,2,2,2,.....,3,3,3,3,......$ is bounded since every term is less than or equal to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

A  sequence from a set is an application from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set, if the set is a finite (for instance {${1,2,3}$}) set it is indeed bounded and the theorem applies. Bolzano Weierstrass could be seen in common language as : if you put an infinite amount of flour grains in a bounded space, you will end getting lumps.